# Ruby - working of "yield" in Iterator each

Tags: ruby

A method can invoke an associated block of code one or more times using the Ruby yield statement. we can also pass values to the block by giving parameters to yield in vertical bars (|). Just like I have done below.

```
  1 def print_name
  2   puts "Hello "
  3   yield "Vikram"
  4 end
  5 
  6 animals = %w( ant bee cat dog elk )
  7 animals.each {|animal| puts animal }
  8 animals.each 
  9 
 10 print_name {|name| puts name}
 11 print_name
```

In my code line number 11 is giving an error that :

```
`print_name': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

This means we cannot use yield in a method without passing a block of code while calling the method.

My question is that, how in my above code "animals.each" (refer line 8) is working without giving any error, if there is a "yield" statement present inside "each" method of ruby?

If it is not present then

```
animals.each {|animal| puts animal }
```

this should not have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby allows you to check whether a block was passed to the current method by using [`Kernel#block_given?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F). [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each), as the documentation says, returns an enumerator if no block is given (which is checked using `block_given?`).

Unlike `each`, your `print_name` method tries to `yield` regardless of whether a block was given, leading to the error on line 11.